# Python: Read list from file

Tags: python

In my config.txt, I have something like this.

```
# Server
server = localhost:8080

# Credentials
username = admin
password = password

# Some list here
important_info = [
    {
         id: 1,
         meaning: something
    },
    {
         id: 2,
         meaning: something else
    }
]

# Another list here
not_that_important_info = [
    {
         id: 3,
         meaning: another
    }
]

# And another one
some_other_info = [
    a,
    b,
    c,
]
```

I want to read the file such that each line would be an element of a list except for lines that should be treated as a list. So far, I have this.

```
def get_params_from_file():
    list = []
    with open('config.txt') as file:
        for line in file:
            if not line.lstrip().startswith('#'):
                # Do something so that it would treat some multiple lines a single line if it contains a list
                list.append(line.rstrip());

    return filter(None, list)
```

Ofcourse, it doesn't work as expected yet. Is there a pythonic way to do this?

Expected output would be:

```
['server = localhost:8080', 'username = admin', 'password = password', 'important_info = [{id: 1, meaning: something},{id: 2, meaning: something else}]', ... ]
```

Comment: For a nested structure like this you may have to write a custom parser, using e.g. recursive descent or [pyparsing](https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/). Considering the particular syntax, there might also exist some magic around `exec` + custom locals mapping that would even work, but a real parser is safer.

Comment: Wouldn't you prefer output as `['server' = 'localhost:8080', 'username' = 'admin' ...]` ? Note that reading `ini` file is possible with https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html